solution-verification| calculate a trigonometric function of the angle of the plane (ABC) with the plane $\alpha$
the problem
The triangle ABC has vertex A in a plane $\alpha$ and is projected onto this plane according to the isosceles right triangle AMN, with $AM=MN=a\sqrt{2}$ M being the projection of B and N the projection of C. If $BM=a\sqrt{3}, CN=2a\sqrt{3}$ calculate a trigonometric function of the angle of the plane (ABC) with the plane $\alpha$, analyzing all cases. pOSSIBLE
the idea

As you can see I intrsected MN with BC in X and the intersection of the 2 planes would be XA.
By the reciprocal of the midline we get that M is the midpoint of XN, so $XN=2a\sqrt{2}$
in triangle XAN, MA= median and height, so traingle XAN is issoscel with $XA=AN=2a$ and by the reciprocal of the theorem of pytaghora we get that $AN\perp XA$
We can calculate BC in the rectangular trapeze MNCB, $BC=a\sqrt{5}$
By the reciprocal of the midline we get that B is the midpoint of XC, so $XC=2a\sqrt{5}$
$AX=2a, ac=4a$ and by the reciprocal of the theorem of Pythagoras we get $CA\perp XA$
Soo the angle between those planes if $\angle CAN=60$ by the reciprocal of the theorem of the angle of 30...so we can easily calculate a trigonometric function of it
I think that my idea is correct, but the phrase from the problem ,,analyzing all cases possible" its making me doubt a bit, because I didn't analyze any cases.
Hope one of you can help me! Thanks!

Not quite sure I follow your description. $N$ is the projection of $B$ and $M$ is the projection of $C$? Anyway, I think possible cases are: 1) B and C are on the same side of the projection plane and 2) they are separated by the plane.

@Vasili I edite my post...sorry for the misspelling .... Also, i dont really understand the other case...Can you please add an answer if you can and explain this case and how I should solve it, because I have no idea! Thank you!

Wait. Is this really "solution-verfication" or something else? If it is indeed solution-veritication, then give the specific step you want checked. If it is not, then simply say 'here is my question, this is my attempt, can you answer/successfully complete my attempt'. Keep in mind that that this question/answer is not just for you but for whoever else may look at this.

It seems that you are assuming that $X$ is not between $M$ and $N$.
I think it is possible that $X$ is between $M$ and $N$.

In the following, I'm going to write my solution.
Let $\theta$ be the angle of the plane $ABC$ with $\alpha$.
We use $X$ that you defined. ($X$ exists since $BC$ is not parallel to the intersection line of the plane $ABC$ with $\alpha$.)
Let $M'$ be a point on $AX$ such that $BM'\perp AX$ and $MM'\perp AX$.
Let $N'$ be a point on $AX$ such that $BN'\perp AX$ and $NN'\perp AX$.
Since $\triangle{BMM'}$ is a right triangle with $\angle{BM'M}=\theta$, we have
$$MM'=\frac{a\sqrt 3}{\tan\theta}\tag1$$
Since $\triangle{CNN'}$ is a right triangle with $\angle{CN'N}=\theta$, we have
$$NN'=\frac{2a\sqrt 3}{\tan\theta}\tag2$$
It follows from $(1)(2)$ that $NN'=2MM'$.

Case 1 : $X$ is not between $M$ and $N$.
Let $D$ be the midpoint of the line segment $NN'$.
Then we have $A=N'$ since $$DM=\sqrt{MN^2-DN^2}=\sqrt{MA^2-MM'^2}=AM'$$
So, $\frac 12NN'=\frac{MN}{\sqrt 2}$ implies $\color{red}{\tan\theta=\sqrt 3}$.

Case 2 : $X$ is between $M$ and $N$.
Since $\triangle{AM'M},\triangle{MM'X},\triangle{NN'X},\triangle{AN'N}$ are right triangles, we have
$$AM'=\sqrt{AM^2-MM'^2}=\sqrt{2a^2-MM'^2}$$
$$XM'=\sqrt{MX^2-MM'^2}=\sqrt{\frac{2a^2}{9}-MM'^2}$$
$$XN'=2XM'=2\sqrt{\frac{2a^2}{9}-MM'^2}$$
$$AN'=\sqrt{AN^2-NN'^2}=\sqrt{4a^2-4MM'^2}$$
Since $AN'=AM'+XM'+XN'$, we have
$$\sqrt{4a^2-4MM'^2}=\sqrt{2a^2-MM'^2}+3\sqrt{\frac{2a^2}{9}-MM'^2}$$
Squaring the both sides and simplifying give
$$MM'^2=\sqrt{(2a^2-MM'^2)\bigg(\frac{2a^2}{9}-MM'^2\bigg)}$$
Squaring the both sides, we get $MM'=\frac{a}{\sqrt 5}$ which implies $\color{red}{\tan\theta=\sqrt{15}}$.
